# how to process values from a form using PHP

Tags: php

I'm able to display the values but my problem is to get the values from the form... This block occurs 6 times (0-41) and they have the same name so i can access/validate them using javascript. ($weeks= $_POST['wt11'];)

```
<input class="chgcolor" type="text" name="wt10" value="1" disabled/> /*week 1*/
 <input type="text" name="wt11" id="w01" onchange="CheckCols('0')" readonly maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $dayarray[0]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="wt11" id="w01" onchange="CheckCols('1')" readonly maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $dayarray[1]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="wt11" id="w01" onchange="CheckCols('2')" readonly maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $dayarray[2]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="wt11" id="w01" onchange="CheckCols('3')" readonly maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $dayarray[3]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="wt11" id="w01" onchange="CheckCols('4')" readonly maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $dayarray[4]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="wt11" id="w01" onchange="CheckCols('5')" readonly maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $dayarray[5]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="wt11" id="w01" onchange="CheckCols('6')" readonly maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $dayarray[6]; ?>" />
```

thanks.

Comment: Show us the form, relevant javascript and PHP.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Personally I recommend changing the names of each one to make them unique, if not then make a function that iterates through each input one of them inputs and appends it to a FormData object to send with jQuery AJAX.

Comment: Use array-style names `name="wt11[]"`. PHP will then make `$_POST['wt11']` an array of all the inputs.

Comment: in my javascript I reference them as: document.getElementsByName("wt11").item(i).value  
document.getElementsByName("wt11").item(i).readonly=true;  
document.getElementsByName("wt11").item(i).style.background etc... how will i reference them in javascript if i changed it to wt11[]..        thanjs